# In Python, how do I transform a string into a file?

Tags: python, string, file, types

There is a read-only library function that takes a file as an argument.
But I have a string.

How do I convert a string to a file, that if you read the file it will return this string?
I don't want to write to disk.

Comment: The question is not about learning how to write a string to disk.  So your purpose in transforming a string to a file would be to exploit some property or behavior specific to a file and not found (or easily emulated) with a string.   If so, which properties/behaviors?  If not, what is this about ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The `StringIO` module:

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> f = StringIO.StringIO("foo")
>>> f.read()
'foo'
```

The `cStringIO` module has the same interface, and is faster, but can't deal with Unicode strings that have non-ASCII characters.

[StringIO documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html)

Answer (score 0):

what do you want?
if you want to read from file just use:

```
file('/path/to/file').read()
```

or

```
open('/path/to/file','r').read()
```

if you want to read string,just do as suggest by Phil